# Magento2 How to copy product attributes and attribute sets from one website to another website?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I have one magento2 web site , and I will build anthor site.
I want to copy product attributes and attbute sets to new web.
What should I to do with mysql ?
May be I can juse copy some table to new web's databases?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default guide for import export.

https://marketplace.magento.com/media/catalog/product/bsscommerce-product-attributes-import-export-1-0-0-ce/user_guides.pdf

If still need extension then this is extension link.

https://www.magebees.com/magento-2-import-export-product-attributes-extension.html

Thanks